# Search keyword and apply filters

Tags: php, mysql

I am encountering a problem I cannot bypass by myself and I that's why I am posting this question. There are a lot of other posts out there that give me half of the answer and I don't really know how to get it done.

I have 3 tables that contain informations about an ad. One table is "ad_names", another is "ad_locations" and the last one is "ad_details".

```
Ad_Names has : ad_title, ad_description, ad_date_added
Ad_Locations has : ad_country, ad_region, ad_city
Ad_Details has : ad_price, ad_author, ad_active
```

Basically I want apply location and details filters for an ad with a certain title.

For example, I want to search "food" keyword in ad-titles and then apply filters like "only from Kansas" or "Only from Kansas + price higher than 500USD". How do I do it?

Comment: use a JOIN then a where clasue

Comment: Being a tad more descriptive would be helpful...Do you have an input form for each of the search parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you will need to join the tables.  do you know if you have a foreign key on the tables?  like is there an Ad_ID field on all 3 tables?  if the tables are large you may also want to index the fields you are searching. once you have all the data you will "filter" it with a where clause.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

```
select * from ad_names as A 
join ad_location as L on A.key=L.key 
join ad_details as D on A.key=D.key
where A.ad_title like '%food%' and L.ad_region = 'Kansas' and D.ad_prics > 500;
```

depending on how your database is setup, you may get a cartesian result there, so you would have to look at your join.  maybe a left outer join limiting the join in an on statement instead of in the where.  it is hard to say without more information.

[Join types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Ad is a table with primary key id, which is a foreign key in each of the other tables (ad_id) then something along the lines of:

**Location:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Ad A
INNER JOIN Ad_Names N ON N.ad_id = A.id
INNER JOIN Ad_Locations L ON L.ad_id = A.id
INNER JOIN Ad_Details D ON D.ad_id = A.id
WHERE N.ad_title LIKE '%food%' AND L.ad_city = 'Kansas'
```

**Price and location:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Ad A
INNER JOIN Ad_Names N ON N.ad_id = A.id
INNER JOIN Ad_Locations L ON L.ad_id = A.id
INNER JOIN Ad_Details D ON D.ad_id = A.id
WHERE N.ad_title LIKE '%food%' AND L.ad_city = 'Kansas' AND D.ad_price > 500
```